# Why does Excel VBA run significantly faster when Outlook is closed?

Tags: performance, vba, excel, outlook

so I have been noticing the VBA code I have written runs significantly faster when Outlook is closed. This is not a sporadic thing: I can run the same code 10x with Outlook open an experience significantly slower processing speeds each and every time, then close Outlook and run 10x and experience significantly faster speeds each and every time. I have also noticed that in addition to Excel "not responding" while code is running, the same goes for Outlook sporadically. I know that Outlook is powered by Word, so it would make sense to me if I was running code in Word. However my Excel VBA in no way utilizes Outlook nor Word. What could the cause of this be? Do Excel and Outlook share some of the same process? I've tried Googling to no avail.

Comment: What's the code doing? Quite a lot of office people have Outlook opened all the time.

Comment: If you can post actual code with timings, some people will likely test.  without either it's difficult to make any comments on this.

Comment: My 2 cents on the investigation: if your code is made of several subs, you might put a timestamp when entering and exiting each macro and print them one after the other in the column A when Outlook is open. Then you do the same in column B when Outlook is closed. I think you will be able to see if the timing increases a bit everywhere, or specifically in a very precise part of the whole procedure. Then you share the result of the test here, I would be very interested in it :)

Comment: Is it a function of memory usage? Perhaps with Outlook running _on **your** machine_, the physical memory usage is high enough that it requires swapping to disk? Also, I've never heard it stated that way that Outlook is "powered by" Word, but I'm sure all the Office programs share some code to a varying degree.

Comment: Not easy without code, but this already happen to me if you do a lot on copy/paste. Outlook react to prepare the paste even if not used in.

Comment: I hadn't remembered I'd commented on this, but recently discovered this issue on Office 2016. Even weirder is that I'm rewriting some code that someone else wrote using the select/copy/paste method (basically recording a macro and not using objects) and the select/copy/paste code actually runs faster with Outlook open than the _cleaned-up_ code written using objects and not selecting anything. This particular code opens a few hundred text files and moves the data to the workbook. It takes about an hour with Outlook open, and about 2 minutes with Outlook closed. I'll do some more testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have experienced this issue.

Both Outlook and Excel are part of the Microsoft Office suite, so I believe the delays boil down to memory sharing between the MS suite programs when they are being used.

When you run a macro, it tends slows down the all MS suite program operations (in my experience). The only real solution I have come up with is to close down MS suite programs before running large macros, including Word and Outlook. I hope this helps.

P.S. Please post your code, I might be able to help you speed it up.